# JAX-RS "Faked" headers in local development

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

This question has two questions:

1. Can I set a flag for local development versus production?
2. Can I alter/add headers before they get to the request handler?

For context, in production there will be a proxy which sets certain request headers before they make it to the JAX-RS request handler. For local development, I would like a to modify the request before it makes it to the request handler and add the headers that we will have in production.

With Django, we would just set `DEBUG = True` and then have a "middleware" that would modify the request headers based on the flag. Is there similar facility in the Java/JAX-RS world? Any suggestion about how this sort of thing is done is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

> Filters can be used when you want to modify any request or response
>   parameters like headers.

The way we set the environment as development or production is by "flagging" it using system parameters in a local database. Other things we do with those parameters are like authentication on/off for test purposes.

Our database is exclusive to the application server (not the customer database if you work with legacy and stuff). You can use embedded like H2/HSQLDB. You can use a local properties file as well.

Pretty much what you can do is read your local parameters, and if development mode is to true, you load a JAX-RS filter to set your headers. You can keep information static or always read from database.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any thoughts on how to tell local development from production?